# Moving to a new domain and using the old one for a new website - how to handle 301 redirects?

Tags: redirect, dns, move

I'm planning to move an old website to a new domain. Then, I would like to use the old domain with a completely brand new different website.

So after the move there would be 2 different websites:

Old website --> brandnewdomain.com

New website --> olddomain.com

The problem I'm having is that **how can I 301 redirect all URLs from the old website to a new domain to keep the visitors flow from search engines and at the same time use the old domain with a new website?** For example I can't 301 redirect the main domain URL when I want to use it for a new website. And also I can imagine more URL conflicts occur.

Have you been in a similar situation? What would you do?

Comment: This is kinda of a loop. Did you think twice before posting this question?

Comment: I don't think it is a loop if I only redirect specific URLs from the old domain. I would like to know if anyone has experienced something similar - reusing the old domain for a new website and redirecting URLs (that are relevant to the old website) to a new domain at the same time. I am interested whether there is some better approach when I want to keep the ranking of the old website.

Comment: This obviously can't work unless all original URLs are unique to the old site and you don't mind listing them in .htaccess. Not worth it overall.