# Building new website on old domain name. How should I redirect the old site?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I recently moved a website to another domain, but I am keeping the original domain for a future website. The recently moved website is **permanently** moved, but I only want traffic to be redirected **temporarily** to the other domain.

I have read countless 301 vs 302 posts, articles, etc. and have failed to find any that address this particular situation. And no one answered this similar question:

[Moving to a new domain and using the old one for a new website - how to handle 301 redirects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28684148/2454385)

But the difference with my question is: I don't even know that I should be using a 301 redirect for this. What's the best way to handle this situation in general?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the .htaccess file to redirect with 307 status code (the successor of 302 in HTTP/1.1)

```
Redirect 307 / http://other-domain/
```

Comment: Note that you need to repeat post request this way, maybe a 308 status will better suit your needs, check it out.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will need to learn more about the difference between GET and POST in regards to redirects, but I think you've put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

*301 Moved Permanently* doesn't mean that the domain name should never be used again; it means that the content the user requested has moved permanently, which is exactly the situation you describe.

(*308 Permanent Redirect* is supposed to supplement *301*, but it is sometimes treated oddly and doesn't work at all on Windows 7 or 8.1 under IE.)

When you decide to re-use the old domain for a new set of resources, you can simply stop redirecting away from it. By then you hope that people looking for the old resource have updated their bookmarks/links thanks to the 301. It might be polite to allow some duration of time for this transition to occur.

Neither *302 Found* nor its replacement *307 Temporary Redirect* is appropriate here, as both misrepresent the situation and do not signify that people should permanently look for the old content in the new location: they're going to be mighty confused when the original domain no longer redirects, allegedly the end of a temporary situation, but then also does not serve the expected content.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a [link](https://css-tricks.com/redirect-web-page/) that you may find helpful. You can also redirect with 308 status code also as @István Rábel suggested